# flatten multiple fields when populating a mongoose query

Tags: javascript, mongoose, populate

I have the following Schema in mongoose with expressjs

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    }, 
    team: {
        type: String
    }, 
});


const dataPointSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
type: {
    type: String, 
    required: true,
    min: 2
}, 
value: {
    type: String, 
    required:  true
},
recorder: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
player: 
  {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now

}
});
```

When I populate the dataPoint with the User, I get the player's team and _id as an object, and i want to flatten it to the below structure:
Population command:

```
    Datapoint.find({}).populate([{path:'player',select:['team']}])
```

current output:

```
{
  player: {_id:"_id from User",team:"team from User"},
  _id: '1',
  type: 'shot',
  value: 'made',
  recorder: 'David',
  date: ' 2021-09-21T21:12:00.025Z',
  __v: 0,
}
```

Desired outout

```
{
  player: "_id from User",
  _id: '1',
  type: 'shot',
  value: 'made',
  recorder: 'David',
  date: ' 2021-09-21T21:12:00.025Z',
  __v: 0,
  player.team: "team from User"
}
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const player = {
  player: {_id:"_id from User",team:"team from User"},
  _id: '1',
  type: 'shot',
  value: 'made',
  recorder: 'David',
  date: ' 2021-09-21T21:12:00.025Z',
  __v: 0,
}

const flatPlayer = {...player ,player: player .player._id,team: player .player.team}

console.log(flatPlayer)
```